# Importing Java classes to Clojure

Tags: java, class, import, clojure

Trying to import a class outside the java-library with no result. I'm runnig counterclockwise on Eclipse Helios. The commons-land-2.6.jar is in the buildpath. I'm new to Clojure and can't figure this out. All help greatly appreciated!

Naturally this works fine:

```
1:7 exp2=> (import '(java.io FileReader))
```

> > java.io.FileReader

but this doesn't:

```
1:6 exp2=> (import '(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils))
```

> > nil

This is the ultimate goal:

1:10 exp2=> (defn whitespace? [character] (. StringUtils (isEmpty character )))

> > java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: StringUtils in this context (repl-1:10)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You made one error - you didn't put space between org.apache.commons.lang and StringUtils class.  This form of import allows you to import several classes from one package, for example:

```
(import '(org.apache.commons.lang StringUtils SystemUtils))
```

if you want to import only one class, then you can use version without parentheses:

```
(import 'org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils)
```

And because functions in StringUtils are static, you need to use following code:

```
(StringUtils/isEmpty character)
```

to invoke their functions